# Unable to install an older version of python

Tags: python, installation

I already have python 3.6.8 and 3.7.3 installed on Windows 10. I had used the "executable installer" from the downloads page to install it.
I have a requirement where I need to install 3.7.1, unfortunately when I use the installer to install python 3.7.1, it complains that "another version of this product is already installed".

How can I install python 3.7.1 without uninstalling 3.7.3?

Comment: Why do you need precisely 3.7.1, exactly?

Comment: The client wants its python program to run on a specific version i.e 3.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a virtual environment? This would resolve your problems nicely. Below are the command line steps to create/activate one on Windows.

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv mypython
mypthon\Scripts\activate
```

If you don't already have pip, use:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

This should resolve your problems, as you can run one version on your vm, and another on your local computer. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I believe virtualenv would create a virtual environment from an existing installation of python on my machine and provide the required isolation. In my case I am trying to install a different version of python (an older version 3.7.1). My current version is Python 3.7.3